# Exclude drawable-large resources from Android build

Tags: android, gradle

Trying to find a way to exclude certain drawable resource files from my build.
Tried using this task but there was not change in the final apk size.

```
task __filteredResources(type:Copy) {
    from('res/') {
        exclude 'drawable-large/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-hdpi/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-xhdpi/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-mdpi/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-land/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-hdpi/'
        exclude 'drawable-large-xdpi/'
    }
    into 'build/filtered_resources'
    includeEmptyDirs = true
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'mergeEnterprisedebugResources' || task.name == 'mergeEnterprisereleaseResources') {
        task.dependsOn __filteredResources
    }
}
```

Anyone tried something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `resConfigs`. Quoting [Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/):

> Starting Android Gradle Plugin 0.7, you can pass information about the configurations your application deals with to the build system. This is done thanks to the resConfig and resConfigs flavor and default config option. The DSL below prevents aapt from packaging resources that don’t match the app managed resources configurations:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...

    resConfigs "en", "de", "fr", "it"
    resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi"
}
```

In your case, `defaultConfig` would contain a `resConfigs` that listed the screen sizes you want, sans `large`.

Comment: So if I'm getting this right, If I will create a reConfig without large screens it wont pack the large resources?

Comment: @TalMihr: That's the idea. I haven't tried it yet personally.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for now as large resources are still packed with the APK but ill try to research it a bit more if ill find the right references to resCofig. Thanks

Comment: @TalMihr Any progress on the research? I encounter exactly the same problem

Comment: this used to work for me but now(gradle plugin v1.3 with gradle v2.9) it says resConfigs() not found. Has this been removed or am I missing something ?

Comment: @AmolGupta: The Android plugin DSL changes sometimes. I have not tried your particular combination of Gradle and plugin versions.

Comment: @CommonsWare resConfigs with density doesn't work anymore... do you came across anyother solution to have it in a single apk?